# SQL Join Same Table and create single row result to complete NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms, self-join

I have only one source table in SQL. I am trying to join it to itself so that i can fill up NULL values and retain the priority values into single row. There are million of records.

FROM THIS:

```
ID1 Source1ID Source2ID Owner   Source1Date Source1Desc Source2Date Source2Desc
8   1asd23    a567nm    Source1 1/1/1900    Active      NULL        NULL
9   1asd23    b555cc    Source2 NULL        NULL        12/1/2000   Ongoing
```

TO THIS (expected result):

```
ID1 Source1ID Source2ID Owner   Source1Date Source1Desc Source2Date Source2Desc
8   1asd23    b555cc    Source1 1/1/1900    Active      12/1/2000   Ongoing
```

So how can i join the table to itself to attain that single row result?

I have tried using the query below and made it as a VIEW but it takes forever to execute just to retrieve 1 row.

```
 --CREATE VIEW  dbo.vw_JOIN AS
    WITH MyTABLE AS (
    SELECT * FROM  TABLE1
    WHERE  Owner = 'Source2')

    SELECT

    T1.ID1,
    T1.Source1ID,
    T2.Source2ID,
    T1.Owner,
    T1.Source1Date,
    T1.Source1Desc,
    T2.Source2Date
    T2.Source2Desc

    FROM TABLE1 T1
    LEFT JOIN MyTABLE T2
    ON T1.Source1ID = T2.Source1ID
    OR T1.Source2ID = T2.Source2ID
    WHERE T1.Owner = 'Source1'
```

[Screenshot of Table values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uzB5.jpg)

Comment: You are not clear about what you want. Use enough words & sentences to be clear. Also, [mcve] please.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select min(id1) as id1, Source1ID, min(Owner) as owner,
       min(Source2ID) as Source2ID, min(Source1Desc) as Source1Desc,
       min(Source2Date) as Source2Date, min(Source2Desc) as Source2Desc
from t
group by source1ID;
```

Comment: @SQLKnows, try the same query, but with MAX() instead of MIN().

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
declare @table table (id1 int, source1id varchar(50),source2Id varchar(50),[owner] varchar(50),Source1Date date,Source1Desc varchar(50),Source2Date date, source2Desc varchar(50)
)
insert into @table

values


(8,   '1asd23',    'a567nm'    ,'Source1' ,'1/1/1900' ,   'Active',      NULL ,       NULL),
(9 ,  '1asd23',    'b555cc'    ,'Source2', NULL      ,  NULL       , '12/1/2000',   'Ongoing')

select a.id1,a.source1id,b.source2Id,a.owner,a.Source1Date,a.Source1Desc,b.Source2Date,b.source2Desc from @table a

inner join @table b on a.source1id = b.source1id and a.source2Id != b.source2Id  where a.owner ='source1'
```

Comment: This code only works for this example. I dont know how the rest of your data is, so it might break. Otherwise use Gordons Example and use MAX instead where the values are wrong